# Attempting to print the number of words that have a certain length

Tags: python

The format for this function is numLen(s,n): where s is a string and n is an integer. What the code is supposed to do is return the number of words in the string that have length n, so:

numLen("This is a test", 4)

Would return 2, since two words have 4 characters.

```
def numLen(s, n):
'''
takes string s and integer n as parameters and returns the number of words
in the string s that have length n
'''
return s.split()
if len(s) == n:
    return 'hello'
```

I attempted to split the string into a list and check the length of each word in that list, but that didn't seem to work out. The farthest I managed to get was returning "hello" when I replaced 4 with 14, just to see if the length code would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
def numLen(s, n):
    return sum(1 for x in s.split() if len(x) == n)
```

I'm using a generator expression, it works like this:

- First, we split the string `s` in words using `split()`
- Then, we filter those words that have exactly length `n`
- We add `1` for each of those that meet the condition
- And finally we add all the `1`s

Comment: `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()` Use a list comprehension.

Comment: Instead of a listcomp, you could also do `sum(1 for x in s.split() if len(x) == n)` or even `sum(len(x) == n for x in s.split())`.

Comment: @DSM He already used the `sum(...)` version. Anyway the list-comprehension is actually faster by about 10%.

Comment: @iKyriaki you're welcome! please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful for you, by clicking on the check mark to its left

Comment: @Bakuriu: my time-travel-fu is on the fritz, I'm afraid.. and whether the listcomp is slower or faster will depend a lot on the sentence.  For me crossover was about about 15 words or so, after which the genexp wins -- YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm assuming this is for a class, the below example is a basic way of accomplishing it (although +1 to Oscar Lopez's solution for Pythonicity :) ).

```
In [1]: def numLen(s, n):
   ...:     # Split your string on whitespace, giving you a list
   ...:     words = s.split()
   ...:     # Create a counter to store how many occurrences we find
   ...:     counter = 0
   ...:     # Now go through each word, and if the len == the target, bump the counter
   ...:     for word in words:
   ...:         if len(word) == n:
   ...:             counter += 1
   ...:     return counter
   ...: 

In [2]: numLen("This is a test", 4)
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: numLen("This is another test", 7)
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: numLen("And another", 12)
Out[4]: 0
```

Comment: @DSM Haha, figured I'd make up for the non-optimal code with some unnecessarily verbose explanations :)

Answer (score 2):

```
reduce(lambda a, w: a+(len(w)>=4), s.split(), 0)
```

Comment: length have to be any number, and it should match the length exactly so it should be `reduce(lambda a, w: a+(len(w)==n), s.split(), 0)` where *s* is the string, *n* is the searched length. But I love the conciseness and the use of reduce in this answer

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
def numLen(s, n):
    num = 0
    for i in s.split():
        if len(i) == n:
            num += 1
    return num
```

Is this what you are going for? This doesn't take into account punctuation (periods, commas, etc.) however.

Answer (score 0):

With this code , you can to obtain the length from each word from you sentence .
With python 2.7

```
a = raw_input("Please give a sentence: ").split() 
for i in range(len(a)):
   print "The Word, ", str(a[i]), " have,", str(len(a[i])), " lengths"
```

With Python 3.x

```
 a = input("Please give a sentence: ").split() 
 for i in range(len(a)):
    print ("The Word, ", str(a[i]), " have,", str(len(a[i])), " lengths")
```